# Third level of drop-down menu hides underneath second level

Tags: html, css, menu

You can find the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xsbWC/1250/

Preferably cross-browser css fix would be fantastic, no JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Yup, it looks broken to me. Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, the question is how do I get the third level menu to appear above the second level (sorry, I thought this would have been clear from the title)

Answer (score 1):

just change the `left` properties to `150px` for the `.third`

http://jsfiddle.net/xsbWC/1251/